# Inconsistent ACL Permission on Pyramid/Websauna

Tags: acl, pyramid, websauna

I'm troubleshooting `is_visible` method on Websauna since it is not working properly (at least for me). The file can be found [here](https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/af56e8aaf5b834b33a04f4f5febda9ee5a96b8c4/websauna/system/crud/views.py#L74).

The issue is, it appears the ACL context suddenly changes from what it shows a line above. Here is the method laced with print logs.

```
def is_visible(self, context: Resource, request: Request) -> bool:
    """Determine if we should render this button.

    :param context: Traversal context
    :param request: Current HTTP Request.
    :returns: Boolean indicating if button is visible or not.
    """
    visible = True
    if self.permission is not None:
        print(context, '&' , self.permission)
        print('******CONTEXT & PERMISSION')
        print(context.__acl__)
        print('******+++++++CONTEXT ACL')
        print(request.has_permission(self.permission, context))
        print('-------------HAS PERMISSION EVAL')
        if not request.has_permission(self.permission, context):
            visible = False

    if self.feature is not None:
        if self.feature not in request.registry.features:
            visible = False

    return visible
```

Here is the log showing how `context` shows different values from the ones `has_permission()` refers to when it denies access.

---

The first two lines in the log below shows call to `resolve_custom_principals` which is a copy of [resolve_principals](https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/5524757e545d27f1198b645626b9bea0a29e9c30/websauna/system/auth/principals.py#L15) but extended with my own ACEs like `(Allow, "mygroup:admin", "add")`...

Reading the log, the context a line above has the correct **acl** including custom ACEs. Why is Pyramid ACL using different context when checking permission in the next line? Which in this case returns ACLDenied.

```
[11:13:01] [websauna.myaddon.auth.principals resolve_custom_principals] ['system.Authenticated', 'user:74', 'mygroup:admin', 'mygroup:manager', 'team_member:1']
[11:13:01] [websauna.myaddon.auth.principals resolve_custom_principals] ['system.Authenticated', 'user:74', 'mygroup:admin', 'mygroup:manager', 'team_member:1']
<websauna.myaddon.crud.org.OrgResource object at 0x7fa021f883c8> & add
******CONTEXT & PERMISSION
[('Allow', 'mygroup:admin', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:manager', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:senior', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:assistant', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:legcle', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:clerk', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:intern', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:admin', 'edit'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:manager', 'edit')]
******+++++++CONTEXT ACL
ACLDenied permission 'add' via ACE '<default deny>' in ACL [('Allow', 'system.Authenticated', 'authenticated'), ('Allow', 'superuser:superuser', 'shell'), ('Allow', 'system.Everyone', 'view')] on context <websauna.myaddon.crud.org.OrgResource object at 0x7fa021f883c8> for principals ['system.Everyone', 'system.Authenticated', 74, 'system.Authenticated', 'user:74']
-------------HAS PERMISSION EVAL
<websauna.myaddon.crud.org.OrgResource object at 0x7fa021f883c8> & add
******CONTEXT & PERMISSION
[('Allow', 'mygroup:admin', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:manager', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:senior', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:assistant', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:legcle', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:clerk', 'add'), ('Deny', 'mygroup:intern', 'add'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:admin', 'edit'), ('Allow', 'mygroup:manager', 'edit')]
******+++++++CONTEXT ACL
ACLDenied permission 'add' via ACE '<default deny>' in ACL [('Allow', 'system.Authenticated', 'authenticated'), ('Allow', 'superuser:superuser', 'shell'), ('Allow', 'system.Everyone', 'view')] on context <websauna.myaddon.crud.org.OrgResource object at 0x7fa021f883c8> for principals ['system.Everyone', 'system.Authenticated', 74, 'system.Authenticated', 'user:74']
-------------HAS PERMISSION EVAL
[11:13:01] [websauna.system.core.session create_session] Skipped session creation for http://localhost:6543/websauna-static/bootstrap.min.css
```

Please let me know if you need more info or how I can make the question clearer.

**UPDATE 1:**
The `is_visible` function is called in the view template to determine which button to render. In my case, it is not showing the buttons yet permissions are set in the context.

```
<div id="crud-page-buttons" class="header-resources">
    {% for button in resource_buttons %}
        {% if button.is_visible(context, request) %}
            {{ button.render(context, request)|safe }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm using:
Pyramid 1.10.4
Websauna 1.0a13

Comment: It looks like you call this function twice elsewhere, based on the output.

Comment: @StevePiercy yes, the function is being called in a loop (currently with 2 buttons). I have added an update to the question showing how it's called. Thanks

Comment: First show the complete output of executing the loop. It looks like you posted only 1.5 loops' output and there is no change in permissions. Second I would guess that the second resource as a different ACL.

Comment: @StevePiercy I've update the question and added more context (no pun intended) to the problem I'm having. Thanks

Comment: The print statements are exactly the same. I do not see what you see.

Comment: @StevePiercy I mean to highlight that ACLDenied line which comes out of nowhere. The context used in `has_permission` is different and so the buttons don't get shown.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect websauna is not invoking your `resolve_custom_principals` function and is rather using its default `resolve_principals` function? I think it's pretty clear that the principals pulled in when `has_permission` are invoked are not the ones from your `resolve_custom_principals` function and thus something is not connected up correctly with this override.